# How to do a request to the server and liberate JavaScript to continue processing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Is there a way to make a request and liberate JavaScript and HTML to do their own thing, leaving the Server to do its thing until it completes, at which point an event grabs control of JavaScript, dumps the data to a designated receiving end and ends the call?

I use this method for calling Python

```
function par_makeHttpObject() {
    try {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (error) {}
    try {
        return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (error) {}
    try {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (error) {}
    throw new Error("Could not create HTTP request object.");
}
```

And I call it as follows:

```
...
var request = par_makeHttpObject();
request.open("POST", "../getFdList?Fds=allFds", false);
request.send();   
var dta = request.responseText.split("\n");
var cnt = 0;
for (var x in dta) {
    try {eval(dta[x]);}
    catch (error) {alert("JS Error - check JS part of syntax!\n" + dta[x]);}
}
...
```

The problem is that JavaScript sits and waits for a reply to the request and the user could be doing something else.  Some calls take 5 minutes...

Any ideas would be appreciated.

DK

Comment: Tagged jQuery, but not using jQuery. You could easily just use `$.ajax()` and leverage the `success: function(){}` to handle the callback when the request has completed. it will allow you to continue as you'd like. Not to mention, it normalizes cross-browser compatability

Comment: @Ohgodwhy   Do you have any sample code for this way of doing the request?

Comment: Sure, about an entire page's worth - [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: @Ohgodwhy  Thanx, will read it now.

Comment: @Musa Excellent article, Thanks!  All you guys rock!  So, I was asking for Asynchronous calls! Got it!  What do you know, another 100 years and I will be a full blown programmer...

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's `ajax()` function instead of rolling your own AJAX solution. `ajax()` defaults to asynchronous requests, so you can pass it a function that is called on request completion:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../getFdList?Fds=allFds"
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Response: " + msg );
});
```

That way, you can call `ajax()`, give it your callback function, and carry on with whatever other processing you need to do.

Another plus for jQuery is that it's pretty well cross-browser without any effort.

Comment: Thank you.  This seems a little different from Jack's but nonetheless I think I understand how this works too.  Very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's very easy in fact. Change the last parameter in your open call to "true":
(I pulled this from w3schools(Yes I'm aware of the sites bad rep, this is just an example))

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
            //THIS IS WHERE YOU GET THE SERVER RESPONSE
    var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Ah!  @Zachrip, So that is what that option is about?  But do I need to revisit and check if the call is ready to return or do I have to prep some responding object to handle a server reply event?

Comment: @DeKoss I added a better example from w3schools.

Comment: There is no need to do the normalization, as OP used a function that already handles it in the first line of his code, if you read the question. `function par_makeHttpObject() {`. He just needs the readystatechange. [Also, obligatory link about why w3schools is bad.](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy 'Tis just an example. And I am aware of w3schools being bad, I just needed an example, this code sample alone works well, disregard where it came from.

Comment: Guys, thank you for these excellent insights.  I thought this was going to be a pit bull, but it looks like a French poodle.  I'm off to test all these ideas.   Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

The best part about AJAX is the ability to continue working on something else while the HTTP request is being made asynchronously.

```
$.post('../getFdList?Fds=allFds', {}, function(response) {
    var dta = response.split("\n");
    // ...
}, 'text');
// continue doing something else here
```

See also: [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: Oh! @Jack , I think I understand this.  So, this is like a listener which stands ready to receive the response...  I will definitely try this and let you know.  But I think this should work...  Thank you...